# Como devolver NULL em LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql

Tenho 2 tabelas que preciso de manipular:

- **intervencaoprioridade :** idintervencaoprioridade , idcelula...
- **celula :** idcelula, nome...

  ```
  SELECT ip.idintervencaoprioridade, zc.nome nome_celula 
  FROM intervencaoprioridade ip 
  LEFT JOIN celula zc ON ip.idcelula = zc.idcelula 
  WHERE ip.idintervencaoprioridade = 22
  ```

O campo *`ip.idcelula`* pode ser `NULL`, mas quando faço esta query retorna  o primeiro registro da tabela *`celula`*. Já vi outros exemplos no *SO*, mas não vi nada que me ajudasse.

Comment: Há aqui algo estranho.. Queres fazer `left join` da entidade `celula` e estás a usar uma `zonacelula`

Comment: corrigido, e ja funciona, estava a fazer um `WHERE ` para um id que nao estava a null. acontece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto pode acontecer a mais utilizadores como no meu caso, deixo a minha resposta e solução caso seja útil a outros.

Quando fiz testes para um `id = 22` este não tinha o campo `idcelula` a `null` dai ele retornar outro valor que por coincidência era o primeiro. Fazendo o teste com mais atenção reparei nesse detalhe, e mudei o registo de teste para um que tivesse o `idcelula` a `null`.